# Adding Binary Numbers in JAVA. NumberFormatException

Tags: java, binary

The problem is when I enter a decimal input. For example 10001.10.
It says NumberFormatException. But when I input just a number without decimal like "1001110" its works fine.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Binary {
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] Condition = { "0", "1", "." };

    //Accept First Input
    String numInp1="";      
    System.out.print("Enter First Binary Number: ");
    numInp1 = in.nextLine();

    //Accept Second Input
    String numInp2="";      
    System.out.print("Enter Second Binary Number: ");
    numInp2 = in.nextLine();

    //numInp1
    String _Array1 []=new String[numInp1.length()];
    //numInp2
    String _Array2 []=new String[numInp2.length()];

    //Catch error in numInp1/_Array1
     boolean flag1 = false;

     for(int i = 0; i < _Array1.length; i++)
     {
         _Array1[i] = String.valueOf(numInp1.charAt(i));
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < Condition.length; j++)
            {
                if (!_Array1[i].equals(Condition[j]))
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (cnt == 3)
                {
                    flag1 = true;
                }

            }

      }
    //Catch error in numInp2//_Array2
     boolean flag2 = false;

     for(int i = 0; i < _Array2.length; i++)
     {
           _Array2[i] = String.valueOf(numInp2.charAt(i));
           int cnt = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < Condition.length; j++)
            {
                if (!_Array2[i].equals(Condition[j]))
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (cnt == 3)
                {
                    flag2 = true;
                }
            }             
     }
     //Getting which of the Array has Higher Input
     if(flag2 == false && flag1 == false)
     {

        int HigherLength = 0;

        if(_Array1.length >= _Array2.length)
        {
            HigherLength = _Array1.length + _Array2.length;
        }
        else
        {
            HigherLength = _Array2.length + _Array1.length;
        }
    //Declaring the size of higher length as the size of Equals[] Array 
        int Equals[] = new int[HigherLength];   
        int _Array1Int[] = new int[_Array1.length];
        int _Array2Int[] = new int[_Array2.length];

      for(int i = 0;i<_Array1.length;i++)
      {
        if(_Array1[i].equals("."))
        {
            _Array1[i] = "6";

        }
        _Array1Int[i] = Integer.parseInt(_Array1[i]);
      }

      for(int i = 0;i<_Array2.length;i++)
      {
        if(_Array2[i].equals("."))
        {
            _Array2[i] = "6";

        }
        _Array2Int[i] = Integer.parseInt(_Array2[i]);
      }

     //_________________________

     int numInp1int = Integer.parseInt(numInp1);
     int numInp2int = Integer.parseInt(numInp2);




     int i,m,n,sum,carry=0;
    for(i=Equals.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        m=numInp1int%10;
        n=numInp2int%10;
        numInp1int=numInp1int/10;
        numInp2int=numInp2int/10;
        sum=m+n+carry;  

        if(sum==1)
        {
          Equals[i]=1;
          carry=0;
        }

        else if(sum==2)
        {
            Equals[i]=0;
            carry=1;
        }

        else if(sum==3)
        {
            Equals[i]=1;
            carry=1;
        }

        else
        {
            Equals[i]=m+n+carry;
        }
    }

    String Equals1[] = new String[Equals.length];

    for(i=0;i<Equals.length;i++)
    {
        try{

        Equals1[i] = String.valueOf(Equals[i]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
        {
         nfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Equals1[i].equals("6"))
        {
            Equals1[i] = ".";

        }
    System.out.print(Equals1[i]);
    }




    }
}
}
```

Comment: What was your effort approaching the problem so far?

Comment: A hint: if you look at the stack trace, you will see immediately what is the problem. Please do that.

Comment: Java cannot have an int that has decimals.   At the locations where  you are trying to parse int numInp1int = Integer.parseInt(numInp1) or   int numInp1int = Integer.parseInt(numInp1) has decimal places even though it is 1.1 or 1.0. That is why you are getting number format exception.

Comment: @user3509209 but I already did this  if(_Array2[i].equals(".")){_Array2[i] = "6";}. To remove the decimal and temporarily change it to "6" and change it back to "." when I convert it to string

Comment: You want  to change . to 6? in numInp1int and numInp2int ?

Comment: @nolexa should I remove my try and Catch on the stack trace?

Comment: @Issac check my answer it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do below changes in your code

Remove below 2 lines-

```
int numInp1int = Integer.parseInt(numInp1);
int numInp2int = Integer.parseInt(numInp2);
```

Replace with below code -

```
    StringBuilder strNum1 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int num : _Array1Int) 
    {
         strNum1.append(num);
    }
    int numInp1int = Integer.parseInt(strNum1.toString());


    StringBuilder strNum2 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int num : _Array2Int) 
    {
         strNum2.append(num);
    }
    int numInp2int = Integer.parseInt(strNum2.toString());
```

Comment: Yeah wow it works thanks!. Do you have any idea how can I properly put my decimal?

Comment: Sorry i did not get it , you are replacing decimal with 6 so its works with above code right? So whats your next question?  Also could you mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I tried replacing the decimal with 6 so that. if Equals1[i] is equal to 6. I will replace 6 by ".".   But when I do that. A number will be added to 6 that instead.

Comment: Since you already replaced 6 with a decimal you will never get this case.  if Equals1[i] is equal to 6

Answer (score 0):

Updating `_Array1` and `_Array2` does not change `numInp1int` and `numInp2int` which you are trying to parse as Integer.

You should learn to interpret error messages in the stack trace. Here you can clearly see where the problem is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10001.1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at q35640801.Binary.main(Binary.java:120)
```

It's in the call `parseInt()` of class `Integer`. It cannot parse decimal numbers like `10001.10`